# CouchDB create a server admin via script

Tags: curl, couchdb, admin, couchdb-futon

this seems simple enough but I've search all over and I can't seem to be able to create server admin users in CouchDB. I can create regular users, but can't figure out how to create one from a script. Can someone demonstrate doing this with curl?

Just to clarify, by server admin user I mean a user who's info is store in the local.ini. In Futon you can login as an admin, click setup more admins, and then create them, but I can't figure out how to replicate this functionality. I've even stepped through what's happening in the jquery couch plugin when I create a new admin in Futon but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. All of the users I add via script just get put in _users table but not in the local.ini. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/configuring.html?highlight=admin#configuring-server-administrators), you can create a new admin via the REST API by working with the `_config` endpoint.

By issuing a `PUT` request against `/_config/admins/:username` (where the request body is the password) a new admin will be created. (provided you have access to do so)

Futon is just using `$.couch.config({...ajax options...}, "admins", username, password);` to accomplish this.

Comment: Hmm I tried that but couldn't get it to work. I'll give it another shot.

Comment: Turned out the problem was I had a Vhost setup that wouldn't allow me to reach the _config handle. Fixed now. Then the solution you gave worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

As per http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/security.html, you can use something like:

```
$ curl -X PUT localhost:5984/_config/admins/myusername -d '"mypassword"'
```